# Positioning blocks relative to an image

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I have the following situation:

- I have a container of a fixed size.
- Inside the container I display an image (of unknown size) that is bigger than the container. I want to display the image as big as possible (but keeping the aspect ratio). I also want the image to be vertically and horizontally centered in the container (so far so good, I know how do that)
- Now I want to have two overlays (of unknown size) over the image: one aligned with the top and one with the bottom of the image.

I cannot get the last point right. If it's unclear then hopefully [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B9Le8/1) should help: there I have the overlays aligned with top/bottom of the *container*. Instead I want them aligned with the *image*. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: relative` does not work on table cells.

From the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group,
>   table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

So, add a wrapper `div` and apply `position: relative` to that instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/B9Le8/5/

```
<div id="container">
    <div> <!-- the wrapper -->
        <img id="img" src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/-J7Q7cUDEFOU/S_bKEoyMSzI/AAAAAAAAGIw/PZJduitsVa0/largeNewGoogleLogoFinalFlat-a.png" />
        <div class="overlay" id="top">Overlay top</div>
        <div class="overlay" id="bottom">Overlay bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>

#container > div {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: @ako This breaks if the image doesn't take up 100% of the width.  Not sure if that matters but it seemed to in the description.  http://jsfiddle.net/B9Le8/8/

Comment: @kingjiv: breaks in what sense? That the overlays are still full width? I can live with that :).

Comment: @ako Yup, that's all I meant.  Wasn't sure if that was intended or not so I figured I'd point it out.

Comment: @kingjiv: Thanks for pointing that out. In fact it'd be even better if it was the same width as the image, but it's not a big deal (in my use-case).

Comment: Hey guys, thanks a lot. I'm just working on an image viewer in [Opa](http://opalang.org) and your answers are helping greatly. It's not finished but if interested you can see it [here](http://iMage.opalang.org) -- hover over an image to see your answers in action :)

Comment: @akoprowski: Looks good. You should check it in Opera, I get a nasty error "XML parsing failed" and the page doesn't show.

Comment: @thirtydot: yup, will do. For now I'm still working on it (on Chrome). I'll check compatibility when I'm done :).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the image in a `<DIV>` and set a `style="background:url()"` in it. Then in that `DIV` , put the `DIV`s that you want to position. It should be easier like that.