# Placing Image in HTML Table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place an image in an HTML table without changing the table borders. What I mean by this is, I'm trying to place the image in a certain cell so that the image stretches outside the cell without increasing the size of the cell (so if there was anything in the way the image would overlap or be overlapped.) By default when I put the image inside the cell it increases the size of the cell so that the text that comes below it gets "pushed down" if you will.

Comment: Placing an image inside anything that is smaller than the image will always result in the container stretching to the image (unless you constrain the container). It sounds like you want the image "over" the cell and spilling out over it. Right?

Comment: I basically want the image margin to be smaller than the image itself.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I would like.

Comment: Look like you are using a Table to create a layout!?  If true, you should use <div> instead.  Using Tables for pure layout is considered bad practice.  ref: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp   ---Even though it is possible to create nice layouts with HTML tables, tables were designed for presenting tabular data - NOT as a layout tool!

Comment: You might be able to place a relative div inside the cell and then an absolute child div that contains the image.

Comment: Thank you Cygnu, I knew I was doing something wrong. I'm new to HTML and this has just been a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a width for the table cell and add `overflow: visible;` to its styles, then the image should just do its thing and push out however far it naturally wants to.

If you want to have the image act independently of everything else in the cell, apply `position: relative;` to the table cell and `position: absolute;` to the image. You can then use `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and/or `left` values accordingly to nudge the image around relative to its (table cell) container.

Comment: `position: relative` [doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712692/positioning-blocks-relative-to-an-image/6712747#6712747) on cells. Though in reality, it seems to work in all browsers but Firefox.

Comment: I stand corrected. I think my revised answer would be "don't use tables for layout."

Comment: You're welcome. Just be sure to browser test and take thirtydot's comment into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

You can use absolute positioning on the image like in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8d92j/2/

You can then hide the image or let it overflow. To hide it, use overflow hidden on the `<div>` and remove absolute positioning on the image.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this, but setting the cell poition to relative the overflow to visible and the image position to absolute should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes to achieve what you want.

First, apply a width value to your table cell

Second, apply the css display:block to your table cell

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50px;display:block">
            <img height="100" width="100" src="myImage.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```